# How to make a function inside a model act like a field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a `Post` model that links wth `PostScore` through ForeignKey:

```
class Post(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
title = models.TextField(max_length=76)
...


class PostScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='score')
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def trending(self):
        score = self.upvotes - self.downvotes
        return score
```

So when I try to sort my Posts like this:

```
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-score__upvotes')
```

It works fine but how would I be able to sort by `trending`?:

```
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-score__trending')
```

the above code creates this error:

```
FieldError at /news/
Cannot resolve keyword 'trending' into field. Choices are: downvotes, id, post, post_id, upvotes, user, user_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Calculate the score difference with annotate method and then order by
>   with that calculated field.

```
Post.objects.annotate(score_diff=F('upvotes') - F('downvotes')).order_by('-score_diff')
```

Comment: This works but it's sorting by just upvotes? Not upvotes - downvotes

Comment: can you show your sample output with score_diff data ? or have a for loop with this object and then print the score_diff and check the results are coming right ?

Comment: My mistake it was a problem with my downvote view not working. The annotate() code works perfect, thankyou.